# Looping through records from one DataTable and populating another DataTable in vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, datatable

I have an asp.net application where I have a datatable ("DataTableA") that returns just one column ("ProductID").

I want to read each row of "ProductID", process some business logic, then copy both those columns (ProductID & ProductIDBusinessLogicValue) to DataTableB. This DataTableB is then displayed on the asp.net page.

What would bhe the best way to read each row of DataTableA ?

Thanks

Comment: why not just create a new column in your first table to hold the computed value (instead of duplicating your table first) -- you don't need a second table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can copy DataTableA to DataTableB, add column and do business logic on each row, something like this:

```
  DataTable dataTableB = dataTableA.Copy();
  dataTableB.Columns.Add("ProcessedValue", typeof(string));

  foreach (DataRow rw in dataTableB.Rows)
  {
    rw.SetField<string>("ProcessedValue", BusinessLogic(rw.Field<int>("ProductID")));
  }
```

Comment: using your logic, I could also just add a new column to DataTableA, correct?

Comment: yes, if you don't need tableA with original schema, btw. sorry for c# version i didn't notice that you  asked vb.net

Answer (score 1):

Here's another approach you might like (linq)

```
Dim table1 As DataTable = ds.Tables("DataTableA")    
Dim query = From product In table1.AsEnumerable() Select ProductID, myCalculatedField    
Dim table2 As DataTable = query.CopyToDataTable()
```

[More Info...](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386921.aspx)